# Which NoSQL DB or Library on top of NoSQL support nosql Publish-Subscribe for unlimited number of clients?

Tags: nosql, publish-subscribe

Which NoSQL DB or Library on top of NoSQL support nosql Publish-Subscribe for unlimited number of clients?

I know redis. Any others? 
I think it is a bit hard to scale out redis to many machines.

Answer (score 0):

I really like redis. Redis is not as hard as it would seem to scale to many machine and in about 6 months there should be a beta for redis-cluster which will make it incredibly simple.